# Read specific cell in sql, using the rows id to choose it with

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a table in my sql database, that comtains data.
In this table, I have the id (int), and two two column names (each nvarchar(50) ).
Now. Say. Using C# in codebehind, I want to place one of the "nvarchar" in a string.
I wish to use the id from my browsers url, to choose the data with.

Lets say, my url is "http://localhost:49530/Forum/Thread.aspx?id=4"
In my table, I have ThreadID, Topic and Message.
So it needs to write the data from "Topic", that has ThreadID=4, into a predefined variable.

I wish to do it in page_load in code behind. And finally show that data in a label on the aspx page.

I am totally blank. (as well as what to google for. Have googled the whole day on this).

I have cooked some code now, using the example given to me. Something is wrong.

```
SqlConnection conn_Kategori = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Computer_Klubben_CommunitySiteConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
int TraadVaelger = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"]);
string OutputToLabel;

    using (conn_Kategori)
    {
        conn_Kategori.Open();
        SqlCommand OverfoerTraadNavnet = new SqlCommand("SELECT KatNavn FROM KategoriTabel WERE Katnavn = @KatNavn", conn_Kategori);
        OverfoerTraadNavnet.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        OverfoerTraadNavnet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KatNavn", TraadVaelger);
        OverfoerTraadNavnet.ExecuteReader();
        OutputToLabel = OverfoerTraadNavnet.ExecuteReader().ToString();
        Stien.Text = OutputToLabel;
        conn_Kategori.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to query the DB with the id from the querystring and display the resulting data on an aspx page?

Comment: Can you post some of your code-behind?

Comment: You have provided no examples of how you're doing any querying of the database. Basically, no matter what you're using, you can do `where ThreadID == id` on your query to achieve that specific thread.

Comment: Hold on. Trying to cook some code first.

Comment: SqlConnection conn_Kategori = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Computer_Klubben_CommunitySiteConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    int KatID = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"]);


        using (conn_Kategori)
        {
            conn_Kategori.Open();
            SqlCommand OverfoerTraadNavnet = new SqlCommand("SELECT KatNavn FROM KategoriTabel WERE ", conn_Kategori);


            conn_Kategori.Close();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string OutputToLabel = string.Empty;

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]))
{
    int ThreadID = 0;
    int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"], out ThreadID);
    if(ThreadID > 0)
    {
        string Sql = "SELECT Topic FROM <tablename> WHERE ThreadID = @ThreadID;";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Sql, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ThreadID", ThreadID);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                OutputToLabel = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not quite the way around, i wanted to go. Still it helped me do some code, using you'r example. Anyway.... I am not shure what i am doing, all trial and error for me. Hehe... I have posted my code above, inside my original post.

Comment: Since you only want a single value returned, I suggest using ExecuteScalar to avoid extra overhead.  I'm noticing that in your code you are not assigning to a SqlDataReader instance and then you are attempting to turn the SqlDataReader into a string... which will only return a string representation of the instance data type, most likely.  After looking at your code, above, I am even more convinced you should use the code example I have provided.

Comment: I also notice that you are returning "Katnavn" from the database, even though you performed the lookup on "Katnavn"... are you sure there isn't a different column you are wanting to return?

Comment: KatNavn is the column i want to return in a string, and write it in the label. The url represent that specific data. KatNavn just holds info such as: ID:1 is Amiga-Hardware, ID:2 is C64-Hardware... And so on... If the url say id=1 then it should return "Amiga-Hardware" in the label.

Comment: Can you give me a list of the columns and sample data for each?

Comment: Great!  It looks like you implemented the core points of the solution I outlined.  I'd appreciate if you could mark my post as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your lines:

```
OverfoerTraadNavnet.ExecuteReader();
OutputToLabel = OverfoerTraadNavnet.ExecuteReader().ToString();
```

You'll probably want something like this:

```
SqlDataReader myReader = OverfoerTraadNavnet.ExecuteReader();
while (myReader.Read())
{
    OutputToLabel = Convert.ToString(myReader["KatNavn"]); // Substitute your "Amiga-Hardware" column name here
}
myReader.Close();
```

More details are in the [SqlCommand.ExecuteReader documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx), for example [passing a CommandBehavor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wy5a0f.aspx) to implicitly close the reader.

Answer (score 0):

I was given some help....
Following code DID the trick. :-)

```
SqlConnection conn_Kategori = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Computer_Klubben_CommunitySiteConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    //int TraadVaelger = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"]);
    string OutputToLabel;
    int TraadVaelger;
    if (!int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"], out TraadVaelger))
    {
        //Errorhandling
        Response.Write("No id was givin");
    }

    using (conn_Kategori)
    {
        conn_Kategori.Open();
        SqlCommand OverfoerTraadNavnet = new SqlCommand("SELECT KatNavn FROM KategoriTabel WHERE KategoriID = @KategoriID", conn_Kategori);
        OverfoerTraadNavnet.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        OverfoerTraadNavnet.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KategoriID", TraadVaelger);
        OutputToLabel = OverfoerTraadNavnet.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        Stien.Text = OutputToLabel;
        conn_Kategori.Close();
    }
```